# what does error SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property ... mean?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-9

I am running an asp.net 3.5 website on IIS 7.5. The default page loads fine in chrome firefox.
However when running in IE 9 I am getting this error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'onBeforeSeek': object is null or undefined
```

I tried to put a metatag in the default.aspx page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

This does not fix the problem? Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This error means exactly what it says: `object is null or undefined`. Probably you're having something like this:

```
some_object.onBeforeSeek = some_value;
```

The error message just means, that `some_object` is null or not defined. Why you're getting this error, it's hard to say without seeing more code. Possible reasons are for example timing (getting property before DOM is ready), invalid HTML etc.